# What is the best way to install xorg and drivers for gpu

Tags: debian, xorg, xfce, amd

I have a 32bit debian, xfce and this GPU:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
```

Since I have installed that system I have problems with xorg (I quess), also I a not a pro with linux so I don't 100% know what I am doing. Can you tell me what is the right way to install/reinstall/repair it? (Problems for example: bad resolution after reboot, cant use video ports at docking station etc.)